# How to make Angular detect mismatching providers in @NgModule at compile time?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, type-safety

### Problem description

In angular one may use an injection token or an abstract class to register a service to the DI container (see [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection)).

However, neither technique seems to inform the developer **at compile time** about accidental mismatches between what shall be provided and what actually is provided. You can simply say, I provide an instance of `IBar`, while you actually supply a class `Foo` that does not satisfy the constraints of `IBar`.

In other languages such as C# or Java registering a service with an interface that does not match will instantly raise an error but it seems that with Typescript/Angular this is not the case which leaves room for accidental mismatches

### Question

How to achieve that an error is raised at compile time when registering a service with a typed token or abstract class inside `providers` when the provider does not match the type?

### Example

For example, both scenarios below will compile without errors but at runtime raise an error:

[image]

**Scenario 1 – Mismatch when using a typed token during configuration:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule, Inject, InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

interface IBar {
  getBar: () => string;
}

export class Foo {
  getFoo: () => string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  template: '<h1>Hello world</h1>'
})
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MyToken) bar: IBar) {
    // this will fail since Foo is injected by DI even though the
    // signature says IBar is received
    bar.getBar();
  }
}

export const MyToken = new InjectionToken<IBar>('foo');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    // note: we register Foo even though the token is typed with IBar
    // and the service also expects to receive IBar
    { provide: MyToken, useClass: Foo },
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    MyComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Scenario 2 – Mismatch when using an abstract class during configuration:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

abstract class Bar {
  getBar: () => string;
}

class Foo {
  getFoo: () => string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  template: '<h1>Hello world</h1>'
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(bar: Bar) {
    // this will fail since Foo is injected by DI even though the
    // signature says IBar is received
    bar.getBar();
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    // note: we register Foo even though the token is typed with IBar
    // and the service also expects to receive IBar
    { provide: Bar, useClass: Foo },
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    MyComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```